# ApolloClient with Angular

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-client

I´m trying to execute a graphql query but I'm getting a network error in client. If I inspect my network layer in chrome, the result is coming correctly. But in my angular component does not.

My query:

```
export const GetAllCorpoQuery = gql`
query getAllCorpo($status: Boolean) {
    getAllCorpo(status: $status) {
        id
    }
}
```

`;

My component method:

```
filter() {
    const {nome, status} = this.entity
    const variables = {
        status
    };
    this.apollo.query<any>({query: GetAllCorpoQuery, variables, fetchPolicy: 'network-only'}).subscribe(({data}) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.corpos = data.getAllCorpo;

        const nome   = new MapColunaAtributo(this.colunas[0], 'nome');
        const status = new MapColunaAtributo(this.colunas[1], 'status');
        this.listPesquisa = [nome, status];
    }
);
}
```

My network layer:
[image]

```
The error:

    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Network error: Error writing result to store for query:
 query getAllCorpo($status: Boolean) {
  getAllCorpo(status: $status) {
    id
    __typename
  }
}

Cannot read property 'getAllCorpo' of undefined
Error: Network error: Error writing result to store for query:
 query getAllCorpo($status: Boolean) {
  getAllCorpo(status: $status) {
    id
    __typename
  }
}
```

Could someone help me?
I´m using angular 4.3.0 and

"apollo-angular": "^1.0.1",

"apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.0.2",

"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.1.12",

"apollo-client": "^2.2.8"

Comment: What are you seeing when you console.log(data)? Also is that id a unique value? I see that you're passing status and expecting an id back. I wonder if apollo is attempting to write a cache entry for you with __typename of getAllCorpo, but you have an array of objects with id not an id for the result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not doing proper mapping in your subscription. In your case try this:

```
this.apollo.query<any>({query: GetAllCorpoQuery, variables, fetchPolicy: 'network-only'}).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.corpos = data.getAllCorpo;

        const nome   = new MapColunaAtributo(this.colunas[0], 'nome');
        const status = new MapColunaAtributo(this.colunas[1], 'status');
        this.listPesquisa = [nome, status];
    }
```

Your response is different structure then specified in subscription.

In response you have structure like this:

```
{
  getAllCorpo: ...
}
```

But in subscription you trying to access like this:

```
subscribe(({data}) => ...
```

I think issue is there. You have to use like this:

```
subscribe(data => console.log(data.getAllCorpo));
```